# AWS Glue control column order in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I'm just starting to experiment with AWS glue and I've successfully been able to pull data from my Aurora MySQL environment into my PostgreSQL DB. When the crawler creates the data catalog for the table I'm experimenting with, all the columns are out of order, and then when the job creates the destination table, the columns again are out of order, I'm assuming because it's created based off of what the crawler generated. How can I make the table structure in the catalog match what's in the source DB?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply open the tabke that create by crawler then click on "edit schema", click on the number at the start of each row and change them, that are the order number of the rows.

Comment: yeah i saw that...seems like there should be an easier way. As an SSIS user, when I set up data source, it preserves the column order automatically. I get that Glue is a new product though, and maybe that's something they'll add down the road. Looks like they've been adding new features and availability zones pretty regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Edit schema as JSON" option in AWS glue. This will open up a JSON editor where you can change the order by moving the JSON elements into the correct order.